# How to show what an alias means

Tags: bash, shell, alias

I can use `compgen -a` to list all the aliases:

```
$ compgen -a
egrep
fgrep
grep
l
la
ll
ls
```

`l`, `la` and `ll` are defined in my `~/.bashrc`:

```
# some more ls aliases
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias l='ls -CF'
```

What command can I run to see what an alias expands to? I have found the `whatis`, `whereis` and `which`, but they don't do what I want.

Comment: The command you probably want to use is `type` which you can use on any command. If your command is an alias or function, `type` tells you the definition; if it's an executable, you get the path; if it's superseeded by a shell built-in, it will tell you so. Available in bourne shell and successors.

Comment: also, if you use `alias` without arguments, you'll get `list of aliases in the reusable
    form 'alias NAME=VALUE' on standard output`

Comment: @Sundeep Amazing..I have not realized this..

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use `alias` (without equals) or `type`

```
$ alias l
alias l='ls -CF'

$ type l
l is aliased to `ls -CF'
```

Comment: The first option `alias l` gave me `-bash: alias: l: not found`.  The second `type l` gave me useful information.